# Method to obtain the solution (hydrostatics)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Mixture of a quantity of liquid A with $x$ lbs of B has a specific gravity of $S$, with $2x$ lbs of B a specific gravity of $S'$, and with $3x$ lbs of B a specific gravity of $S''$. Show that
>   $$2(S-S_1)(S_2-S')=(S_2-S)(S'-S_1)3(S-S_1)(S_2-S'')=(S_2-S)(S''-S_1),$$
>   where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the specifc gravities of the liquids.

I do know that$$
SG=\frac{V_1 SG_1 + V_2 SG_2}{V_1+V_2}=\frac{W_1+W_2}{\dfrac{W_1}{SG_1}+\dfrac{W_2}{SG_2}},
$$
what I do not understand is $S_1$ and $S_2$, which is stated to be specific gravities of "liquids". Does it refer to the liquid before $x$ lbs of B was added or does it refer to after?
Also I do not know weather liquid A is a mixture of S1 and S2 and weather the given weights are added to the same initial mixture i.e x lb then 2x lb to mixture with x lb then 3x lb to mixture having x lb and 2x lb, or the weights are added to seperate mixtures.

Any form of enlightening is appreciated.

Comment: isn't $S_1$ just your $SG_1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with
$$
W_1  = S_1 \,V_1 \quad\quad W_2  = x = S_2 \,V_2 \quad\quad W_1  + W_2  = S_1 \,V_1  + S_2 \,V_2  = S\left( {V_1  + \,V_2 } \right)
$$
then the data you are given tell that
$$
\eqalign{
  & W_1  + 2W_2  = S_1 \,V_1  + 2S_2 \,V_2  = S'\left( {V_1  + \,2V_2 } \right)  \cr 
  & W_1  + 3W_2  = S_1 \,V_1  + 3S_2 \,V_2  = S''\left( {V_1  + \,3V_2 } \right) \cr} 
$$

so you get the system
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  S_1 \,V_1  + S_2 \,V_2  = S\left( {V_1  + \,V_2 } \right) \hfill \cr 
  S_1 \,V_1  + 2S_2 \,V_2  = S'\left( {V_1  + \,2V_2 } \right) \hfill \cr 
  S_1 \,V_1  + 3S_2 \,V_2  = S''\left( {V_1  + \,3V_2 } \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
in the five unknowns $V_1,V_2,S_1,S_2,S$.

Can you continue from here ?

Comment: @Abdullahshuaib: try and solve the linear system for $V_1$ and $V_2$ ...